# Explanation of the etymology of "subjuntivo"

Tags: etimología, verbos, subjuntivo

I know that *[indicativo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LO2GGPy)* comes from the Latin word *indicatīvus*, and this one from *indicô, -âs, -âre, indicâvî, indicâtum*, meaning "to indicate". The reason for that name is that the indicative tenses point out or state objective, proven facts, and we are just *indicating* that fact.

Nonetheless, the *[subjuntivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YXmw8Bc)* word comes from Latin *subiunctīvus*, and this one from *subiunctus* (from *sub*, "under", and *iungô, is, ere, iûnxî, iûnctum*, "to join"), meaning *to join beneath, to subordinate*.

But the subjunctive mood is used to state facts as "virtual, non-specified, non-verified or non-experimented". So what does that etymology have to do with the subjunctive mood and its uses?

Comment: Does your question not already contain the answer in the form of the word subordinate? As in subordinate clause.

Comment: @mdewey maybe, but the question is about the etymology itself. The link between the current meaning of "subjunctive" and its etymology is not as clear as in the indicative case. And not every verb in subjunctive mood must go in a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **subjunctive** appears in English as an adjective and then as noun, [according to EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/word/subjunctive) (usually a good source). It is attested as the

> "mood employed to denote an action or state as conceived and not as a
>   fact," 1620s, from earlier adjectival use of *subjunctive* (1520s),
>   from Late Latin *subiunctivus* "serving to join, connecting," from
>   *subiunct-*, past participle stem of Latin *subiungere* "to append, add at the end, place under," from *sub* "under" + *iungere* "to join
>   together" (from nasalized form of PIE root **yeug-* "to join"). **The
>   Latin *modus subiunctivus* probably is a grammarians' loan-translation
>   of Greek *hypotaktike enklisis* "subordinated," so called because the
>   Greek subjunctive mood is used almost exclusively in subordinate
>   clauses.**

(Emphasis mine.)

The names of grammatical categories are always conventional and, in Western European languages, often derived from Latin models, in turn derived from Greek grammar, in the manner explained above. Grammarians no longer try to force modern languages into classical molds, but the traditional names remain.

Answer (score 1):

In 1771, when the RAE introduced its first *Gramática* to the world, the subjunctive mood was defined in a different way than today's. Then the subjunctive verb tenses were described like this:

> el que necesita juntarse con otro verbo expreso ó suplido que perfeccione el sentido de la oración

This is, every verb tense that cannot stand alone in a sentence and needs from another verb (present or omitted) to make sense, that tense is a subjunctive one. So, the definition of *subjunctive* was not about the *mood*, but about the way you use it in a sentence, and making it clearer the relation between the etymology of the word itself and its definition, as the subjunctive verb tenses really needed to be subordinated to another tenses.

But there was a time in which the definition of *subjunctive* changed, and that leads me to [another question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22707/12637)...